# How do I read a txt file (containing integers) in ARM and then print them out?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm having difficulty understanding file input in ARM. I'm trying to run this program with a .txt file as my only argument that contains a few integers and I can't make any progress.

For my assignment, I was given all the code below aside from the code between the two comments (which is code I wrote myself)
Here is the code that I've written so far.

```
.file "sum.s"
.text
.align  2
.global main
.type   main, %function
main:
push {lr}   

//my code

ldr r0, =rdfmt
sub sp, sp, #4
mov r1, sp
bl scanf
ldr r2, [sp, #0]
add sp, sp, #4
mov r1, r2
bl printf
ldr lr, [sp, #0]
add sp, sp, #4
mov pc, lr
//end my code 

pop {pc}    

.section    .rodata
rdfmt:        .asciz "%d"
prtfmt:       .asciz "sum is %d\n"
```

I'm supposed to do more than indicated with the program above, but let's just say I want to be able to print the first integer in a .txt file containing 5 integers.

so my input.txt would be

```
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
```

and my output would be

```
    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to pass a format for `printf`.  `r0` is call-clobbered so it's not still holding a pointer to that string.  In fact `r0` holds the return value.  Use a debugger and/or read the calling-convention / ABI docs.

Also you're using using the scanf conversion result as a return *address*, not a return value.